# Ndless makefile/make install error linux

Tags: linux, git, compiler-errors, installation, raspberry-pi3

I have read up [here](https://github.com/ndless-nspire/Ndless/wiki/Ndless-SDK:-C-and-assembly-development-introduction#on-linux-distros) about how to install the Ndless SDK on Linux, and I have followed as much as I could, like installing packages via terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get install [package]
```

all goes well until I reach the root "make" command. I do as the directions say, in ~/Ndless, and run "make" in the terminal. I receive this error each time I try to do this:

```
make -C ndless-sdk
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Ndless/ndless-sdk'
make -C libsyscalls
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Ndless/ndless-sdk/libsyscalls'
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=arm926ej-s -std=c11 -nostdlib -O3 -fPIE -mlong-calls -Wall -Werror -I ../include/ -I ../thirdparty/nspire-io/include/ -D_TINSPIRE -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -c realpath.c -o realpath.o
realpath.c: In function 'realpath1':
realpath.c:50:12: error: 'PATH_MAX' undeclared (first use in this function)
  char left[PATH_MAX], next_token[PATH_MAX];
            ^
realpath.c:50:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
realpath.c:50:23: error: unused variable 'next_token' [-Werror=unused-variable]
  char left[PATH_MAX], next_token[PATH_MAX];
                       ^
realpath.c:50:7: error: unused variable 'left' [-Werror=unused-variable]
  char left[PATH_MAX], next_token[PATH_MAX];
       ^
realpath.c: In function 'realpath':
realpath.c:159:25: error: 'PATH_MAX' undeclared (first use in this function)
   m = resolved = malloc(PATH_MAX);
                         ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:21: recipe for target 'realpath.o' failed
make[2]: *** [realpath.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Ndless/ndless-sdk/libsyscalls'
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'build-libsyscalls' failed
make[1]: *** [build-libsyscalls] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Ndless/ndless-sdk'
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'build-ndless-sdk' failed
make: *** [build-ndless-sdk] Error 2
```

Also, I created a .bash_profile in my home directory, and added this to it, as shown in the directions:

```
export PATH="/home/pi/Ndless/ndless-sdk/toolchain/install/bin:/home/pi/Ndless/ndless-sdk/bin:${PATH}"
```

When the directions displayed **PATH environment variable** as bold, I took to the web and found that .bashrc was the PATH, so I added the same above code to it.

**LAST EDIT**

https://pastebin.com/C7rWJp5Y

```
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Ndless/ndless/src/tools/MakeSyscalls'
php ./mkSyscalls.php "idc" "../../../../ndless-sdk/include/syscall-addrs.h"
/bin/sh: 1: php: not found
Makefile:9: recipe for target '../../../../ndless-sdk/include/syscall-addrs.h' failed
make[4]: *** [../../../../ndless-sdk/include/syscall-addrs.h] Error 127
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Ndless/ndless/src/tools/MakeSyscalls'
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'build-MakeSyscalls' failed
make[3]: *** [build-MakeSyscalls] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Ndless/ndless/src/tools'
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'build-tools' failed
make[2]: *** [build-tools] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Ndless/ndless/src'
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'build-src' failed
make[1]: *** [build-src] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Ndless/ndless'
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'build-ndless' failed
make: *** [build-ndless] Error 2
```

Comment: look at the last edit for new errors.

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere the string **user** appears in the below commands for changing directories, just replace that with your username in Linux.

#### Update apt-get

> sudo apt-get update

If this fails make sure you temporarily disable your VPN connection; it did for me.

#### Install packages

> sudo apt-get -y install git && sudo apt-get -y install gcc && sudo apt-get -y install binutils && sudo apt-get -y install libmpfr-dev && sudo apt-get -y install libmpc-dev && sudo apt-get -y install zlib1g-dev && sudo apt-get -y install libboost-program-options-dev && sudo apt-get -y install wget && sudo apt-get -y install texinfo && sudo apt-get -y install python2.7 && sudo apt-get -y install python2.7-dev && sudo apt-get -y install python3 && sudo apt-get -y install python3-dev && sudo apt-get -y install php && sudo apt-get -y install libboost-dev && sudo apt-get -y install build-essential && sudo apt-get -y install gcc-arm-none-eabi && sudo apt-get -y install python

#### Clone Ndless into home

> git clone --recursive https://github.com/ndless-nspire/Ndless.git

#### Run build_toolchain

> cd Ndless/ndless-sdk/toolchain && ./build_toolchain.sh

#### Ndless command path

> export PATH="/home/**user**/Ndless/ndless-sdk/toolchain/install/bin:/home/**user**/Ndless/ndless-sdk/bin:${PATH}"

#### Ndless Makefile

> cd /home/**user**/Ndless && make

All of this will take a long time (took 5 hours for me), depending on your hardware and maybe internet connection.

[image: output]

## Notes

Lets try building this simple file:

```
// main.cpp
#include <libndls.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_config.h>

int main() {
    SDL_Surface *screen;
    nSDL_Font *font;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(320, 240, has_colors ? 16 : 8, SDL_SWSURFACE);
    font = nSDL_LoadFont(NSDL_FONT_TINYTYPE, 29, 43, 61);
    
    SDL_FillRect(screen, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 255, 0, 0));
    nSDL_DrawString(screen, font, 10, 10, "Hello, world! \x1");
    
    SDL_Flip(screen); // update screen
    SDL_Delay(3000); // wait for 3 seconds
    
    SDL_Quit(); // get out of SDL screen, returns to normal nspire
    return 0;
}
```

To generate the makefile:

```
nspire-tools new main
```

Then run:

```
make
```

The output should look something like this:

> user@DESKTOP-6IBLUJD:/mnt/d/NdlessSDK/workspace/cpp/test$ make

> nspire-g++ -Wall -W -marm -Os -c main.cpp -o main.o
> mkdir -p .
> nspire-ld main.o -o main.cpp.elf
> genzehn --input main.cpp.elf --output main.cpp.tns.zehn --name "main.cpp"
> make-prg main.cpp.tns.zehn main.cpp.tns
> rm main.cpp.tns.zehn

I did this in WSL, so I had to do cd `cd /mnt` to reach my main drives to compile.

You can also try running that in Firebird Emulator with Ndless installed!

If you skip ahead, and decide to run make without fully completing the ./build_toolchain command (probably resulting from an error), don't be surprised if the make command fails. The output for the failure will be something about a

> undeclared PATH_MAX

But, if you install all the necessary packages, and fully build the commands with success, Ndless should compile and function without issue.

If you get a `nspire-gcc: Command not found` while building the SDK, make sure you set the `PATH` variable correctly. I did `echo "$PWD"` which shows my current directory, which I used for Ndless path.